# Displaying an image in html from persistent browser file storage

Tags: javascript, html, browser, filesystems

So I saved an image into the browser LocalFileSystem and the images is accessible if I input the following link in the browser

```
filesystem:http://192.168.1.6:3000/persistent/downloaded-image.png
```

However when I put the link into a  tag, the browser can't open the image.

So when I go into the inspect elements and right click on the link as so:
http://prntscr.com/n089n5
It takes me to

```
http://192.168.1.6:3000/filesystem:http:/192.168.1.6:3000/persistent/downloaded-image.png
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is how I'm displaying the image

```
function displayImageByFileURL(fileEntry) {

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = fileEntry.toURL(); //
    document.getElementById("console").appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Why not load the image using script, take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158887/saving-and-loading-an-image-from-localstorage

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I updated the question